# Set partition with duplicates

Tags: combinatorics

I am thinking about [problem 88](https://projecteuler.net/problem=88) in Project Euler and I think it might be related to set partitioning.

For the numbers below 24000, there are at most 14 prime factors (excluding 1 and themselves). There are at most only 5 distinct prime factors.

Is there an algorithm to generate distinct partitions of a set when there are duplicates present?